# Тэги html отправляются как текс

Tags: javascript, html

```
$('form.send-message-form').ajaxForm({
        url: SK_source() + '?t=message&a=send_message',

        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.message-textarea').attr('disabled',true);
        },
        success: function(responseText) {

            if (responseText.status == 200) {

                if ($('.text-message-wrapper').length == 0) {
                    $('.text-messages-wrapper').html(responseText.html);

                } else {
                    $('.text-messages-wrapper').append(responseText.html);
                }

                $('.text-messages-container').scrollTop($('.text-messages-container').prop('scrollHeight'));
            }

            $('form.send-message-form').clearForm();
            $('.message-textarea').val('').attr('disabled', false).keyup().focus();

            SK_progressIconLoader($('.textarea-container').find('.options-wrapper'));
        }
    });
```

Нужно что бы выводилось как html

Comment: Проблема на стороне сервера внешне

Answer (score 0):

1. Как то так:

> ```
> var $wrapper = $('.text-messages-wrapper');
> $wrapper.html('');
> var html  = $.parseHtml(responseText.html);
> $wrapper.append(html);
> ```

2. Каждое $ выполняет обход всего DOM дерева заново, поэтому выгоднее вычислить элемент один раз, записать его в переменную и работать с ним дальше.